# Why Does Using a Filter Object for Assignment in a Python Pandas Dataframe Fail?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a regular expression to find columns in a dataframe, multiply those columns by another column in the same dataframe, and update the existing dataframe with those results.  When doing so with a filter object, however, the operation fails with:
'''

```
Value Error:  Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

'''
However, when evaluated independently, the right-hand side and left-hand sides of the equation are both dataframes with identical indices and column headers.
'''

```
###Set up dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(data={"N1":np.arange(1,4),"P1":np.arange(2,8,2),"N2":np.arange(3,12,3)},index=["R1","R2","R3"])

###Find target columns, modify them, and return them
df[filter(re.compile(r"^N",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)]=df[filter(re.compile(r"^N",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)]*np.array(df[filter(re.compile(r"^P",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)])
Value Error:  Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

###Yet when running the left- and right-hand sides separately, one finds:
df[list(filter(re.compile(r"^N",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns))]
Out[11]: 
    N1   N2
R1   4   12
R2  16   48
R3  36  108

df[filter(re.compile(r"^N",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)]*np.array(df[filter(re.compile(r"^Q",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)])
Out[12]: 
     N1    N2
R1   16    48
R2  128   384
R3  432  1296
```

'''
The issue is with assigning into a dataframe using a filter object.  The above Value Error can be fixed by forcing the lefthand side filter object into a list such as:
'''

```
df[list(filter(re.compile(r"^N",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns))]=df[filter(re.compile(r"^N",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)]*np.array(df[filter(re.compile(r"^P",re.IGNORECASE).search,df.columns)])
```

'''
Why does using the filter object on assignment into a Pandas dataframe fail?  Is this intended behavior?

Comment: As an aside, consider using `df.columns.str.contains(r"^N", regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`. Not `filter`. I'm not sure what is the cause of the discrepency here, but I don't think pandas indexing is designed around handling arbitrary iterators cleanly, I would not have expected a non-sequence like `filter` to work at all

Comment: So I would just stick to the [documented choices](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)